# Why are my media queries not being recognized by my editor(VS Studio)?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, media-queries

I am new to web developing and I began making a webpage, however, I designed it for a desktop before mobile. Now I am trying to use media queries but my editor (VS studio) is not picking up on the media queries. When I write "@ media screen and (max)"[screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaYFx.png) it does not give me the option to put in "max-width." I checked all my code and it is correct until there so I do not know why it is not working. I have attached screenshots and a codepen link. Any help is appreciated.

https://codepen.io/jayson-caguana/pen/BajWxZQ

```
/*  FOOTER */
footer {
  background: burlywood;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .features {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: `max-width: 300px` is quite a small screen size, so try setting it higher, mabye to something like 700px. (you can always turn it back) Do you still get the same issue?

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.